# How to Add a third party module for nginxinc/nginx-ingress configuration in kubernetes?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Goal :

I am trying to include a thirdparty module a Http_more_headers to provide a custom name to the server in the headers.

I am able to [build a custom controller image](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/building-ingress-controller-image/) with the module installed with a slightly tweaked DockerFile.

Issue:

To enable this third party module I need to add the load_module directive in the nginx.conf I am however confused on how the ingress controller interprets the nginx.conf file. If I add the load_module in the server-snippet annotation, will it work? or do I have to modify the .tmpl file to enable the third party module? or should I just modify the nginx.conf and use a COPY during the image build itself? which would be the best way to achieve the goal?

Comment: Hey, i was tryna do the same thing for opentelemetry modile. By any chance can you add the Dockerfile you used to build your custom controller image successfully. I am stuck at this process.

Answer (score 3):

Use the "main-snippets" configMap key under "data" followed by the value "load_module <module_path>"

example:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
data:
  main-snippet: load_module /usr/lib/modules/xyz_module.so
```

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/configmap-resource/).

Comment: is not working on my kubernetes/nginx-ingress, maybe because it is different.